# Getting error while importing rest-assured packages

Tags: java, rest, api, rest-assured

[image: I am using maven project, in which I already created the dependency for rest-assured. When I am trying to import rest-assured package, I am unable to do. I am getting an error.]

I am using maven project, in which I already created the dependency for rest-assured. When I am trying to import rest-assured package, I am unable to do. I am getting an error.

Comment: put your pom.xml as well.

Comment: As `static` is a reserved word, it cannot be a package name. Therefore something is missing from your imports.

Comment: why are people downvoting it?

Comment: @AmitK :    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: Can you check if this version of dependency is downloaded and present in your .m2 folder, which will be there in your home directory ?

Comment: @AmitK yes it is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created wrong maven dependency
Was trying to import io.restassured while developed jayway restassured dependencies